# Macros Starting Crashing Today

Tags: vba, excel

Quick overview: I develop Excel Macros for a firm. The Macros are used in a daily basis for more than 200 workers. These 200 workers connect the Local Machine to a common server (there actually 3 servers) and run the Macros from there.

Problem: Today in the morning some of these Macros (different Macros) starting crashing Excel with the tipical message "Excel has stopped working". These Macros (which I didn't update) run every day without a problem. Today, just like magic, they starting crashing for different lines of code which only common denominator is that they use a lot of resources.

Ex:

```
sh.UsedRange.Value = sh.UsedRange.Value (the UseRange is alcually a pretty small range)
Application.Calculate
wb.Sheet1.Move
```

I understand these are functions that take a lot of memory but still they have been working for months without a problem until today. I know this could be more like IT kind of problem but since I'm trying to solve this issue, I thought maybe one of you either had this problem before or know a possible cause (like a Windows update).

IT already reinstalled Excel in all the servers that we use for remote connection but the problem persists.

Any Idea?

Thanks a lot,

Comment: check the event log. look for exception code. did you update your antivirus recently?

Comment: The application.calculate will calculate all open excel files and if the user has a file with many array or volatile formulas open, it could cause the cascade you are describing.

Comment: Got it @ScottCraner but we run this Macro (Application.Calculate) everyday at least 100 times at just today it started breaking everytime for every specific case we run it. It is very weird that just today when we starting receiving the rest of the errors this one came out.

Comment: @cyboashu I asked the IT department if the update the Antivirus. Will let you know what they Say...

Comment: Has your IT installed MS Office updates? I remember about 4 years ago MS provided an update that caused some of my code to stop working because it screwed up some ActiveX objects. Worth looking into!

Comment: @rohrl77 Something like that happened to me (shame that I didn't see your message earlier). Microsoft lunched an update that messed my code up. The servers have Automatic Updates on and grabbed whatever update is launched. This last update was messing everything up. I uninstall the update an everything works fine again. Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Ok, here is what happened in case you guys see this problem in the future:

Everything is Microsoft fault's. They launched an update to fix some Excel bugs and instead of fixing them, the server that automatic updated their versions, got really messed up. This updated was launched on Mar/14/2017 (2 days Ago).

I made some research and this sounded very weird to me. They launched an update to fix Excel 2010 bugs and now my Macros are breaking without changing the code? It had to be that and there it was.

Here's the Log: 
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3178690/ms17-014-description-of-the-security-update-for-excel-2010-march-14-20

Just keep your head up if you have Automatic Updates on in your computer and see problems like these happening. In case you find that's the problem, just remove the update from your Excel.

Regards,

Comment: Good to know! Thanks for the link, as it is very likely that I will also get hit by this update.

Answer (score 1):

I am currently running into a similar issue with an Excel VB script utilizing the Today() function. The script freezes up and becomes unresponsive when the date is 03/17/17, but if I change the system date to 03/16/17, everything works great.

It appears that there were a number of Microsoft Office Updates on 03/16/17, so I am going to try and remove them one by one and see if that fixes the issue. I'm starting out with the Security Update for excel, KB3178690.

Update -- confirmed, removing Microsoft Security Update for Excel KB3178690 fixes the crashing issue related to the date function after 3/17/17. Probably some deeper reason to this, such as activeX forms or something (of which I don't believe this script utilizes), but at any rate it's working now.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what was happening to me. I don't know how and when Microsoft is going to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

My laptop ran the latest windows 7 updates last night and since then all my macros have stopped working. I have had to roll my laptop back to a point before last nights updates and everything is now working fine again. Think there is a major issue with the latest Microsoft update releases.